# Where is the created File from Xcode on Mac get stored?

Tags: c, xcode

I am new to Xcode on MAC and I am using that for C coding. I WROTED a code that create a .dat, .docx file, it returned no error but I can't find the files I created. I know the code works because i tried on my Visual studio i have on my PC, and i found the files i created, where are they on MAC?.

The file does not exist, this code should create the file. On pc, the file would appear in the default location where I installed my Visual Studio, but on Mac, i don't know where it is.

```
FILE *fin,*fout;
fout = fopen("out.dat", "w");
```

Comment: right click it and select 'Show in Finder' ?

Comment: I'm just curious - why did you capitalize the word *wroted*? There is no such word in English, what did you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

Without posting your code, there's not much we can do but guess.

My guess is... you specified a relative path for the file output in your program so it was based on your working directory.

When your program is running, open a terminal and type

```
lsof -p <PID> | grep cwd
```

where `<PID>` would be the process id of your C program that's running.

This would show you the current working directory and your output file's location should be based on this path.

Comment: Sorry, first time using this website, i edit the post with code.

Comment: Yes, that's a relative path since it doesn't start with `/`, so my guess should be correct. Most likely, the working directory will be somewhere in your home directory, `~`, but to be sure, try the command above while your program is running and it should give you the actual path.